# Spring MVC classes not found

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, classnotfound

I'm trying to run a Spring MVC project in STS with Tomcat 6.0 server. But I have these 2 errors which I can't resolve:

```
Class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource' not found [config set: projectName/web-context] root-context.xml    /projectName/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring Spring Beans Problem
Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver' not found [config set: projectName/web-context]   servlet-context.xml /projectName/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet Spring Beans Problem
```

I suspect this has to do with the build path. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should accept your own answer if it indeed solved your problem

Comment: No problem, it's preferrable to actually edit an existing answer as to not cause an inflation of answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These problems were solved by right clicking project name in Package Explorer->Spring Tools->Add Spring Project Nature. (Don't know what really happened, only that problems were gone afterwards.)

Comment: Really helped me. I already added Spring project nature in my project. What I did remove and then again add Spring Project Nature solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

For me it was resolved by disabling Maven Workspace Resolution. Most of these kind of minor issues were caused because of enabling Maven Workspace Resolution.

Id suggest to do yourself a favor by disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I resolved this issue deleting this mapping in the spring config-file. 
The class didn't exist, but the mapping remained. The mapping was old. 
Delete the old mapping in the spring config-file and spring will work.